# Splitting string by colon in Python

Tags: python, regex, string, list, python-re

I have a reminder app and I need to split the time like `3:30 a.m.`. I used `re` module but I failed.

What I'm trying to do is split the time by colon in front of the words in list. But list has multiple words. Like `a.m.`, `am`

The program should try the words until it gets the right match, and split the time by colon, such as hour and minute. `13:25` to `[13, 25]`.

Here is an example:

```
import re

am = ['a.m.', 'am', 'ante meridiem']
timeinp = 'reminder for 3:30 am'

for a in am:
    gettime = re.search(fr'\b\d?\d:\d\d\b {a}', timeinp).group(0)
    gettime = re.split('[:]', gettime)
    print(gettime)
```

This code gives me `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a single regex with capturing groups to instantly get access to hours and minutes if there is a match:

```
import re

am = ['a.m.', 'am', 'ante meridiem']
timeinp = 'reminder for 3:30 am'

a = "|".join(map(re.escape, am))
gettime = re.search(fr'\b(\d{{1,2}}):(\d{{2}})\s*(?:{a})', timeinp)
if gettime:
    print(list(map(int, gettime.groups()))) # => [3, 30]
else:
    print("no match")
```

See [Python demo](https://ideone.com/qRYdWN)

Note that [`gettime.groups()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.groups) contains a *tuple containing all the subgroups of the match, from 1 up to however many groups are in the pattern.* The capturing groups are all those parts of the pattern enclosed with `(...)`.

You need to `re.escape` your `am` list items, otherwise, `.` matches any char. You need to use `\.` outside a character class to match a literal dot.

Comment: Wiktor, you could have fixed the regex string by escaping the brackets.  Was wondering why you decided to delete it or to use another regex

Comment: Nothing "wrong" per se.  I'm commenting about your original post that you deleted and decided to revert to the OP's version of the regex.  \d{1,2} is being evaluated to "(1,2)" because of the `f` modifier

Comment: @user120242 It makes little difference. Reverted to using `{1,2}` and `{2}`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew How to match this `re` something like `1.5` or `.5`?

Comment: @June `\d+(?:\.\d+)?`

Comment: `self.hour = 'hours later, hour later'`

`h = "|".join(map(re.escape, self.hour))`

`gettime = re.search(fr'\b(\d+(?:\.\d+)?{{1,9}})\s*(?:{h})', self.inp)`

I edited the code to get just hour, but this gives me `multiple repeat at 16` error.

Comment: @June `self.hour` is a string, why do you `join` it? See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/B5w2cX) to learn how to access each group individually.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the brackets for `self.hour`. I'm trying to get something like `3.5` or `.5` from`set reminder for <hour> a.m.` Please help.

Comment: @June This is now becoming unclear, I hope [this snippet](https://ideone.com/UVQVSx) will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, you're getting an `AttributeError` due to `re.search()` returning `None` in cases where an item stored in `am` results in no match within your loop.

The below example is similar to others in handling cases in which `re.search()` returns `None`, however it:

- Uses a lookahead to in the pattern as to not include the `am` item in the match returned.
- Further processes the match into a list of 2 `int` instances instead of `str`
  instances.
- Breaks the loop following `print(gettime)` to stop any
  further iterations and keep the list value assigned to `gettime`
  available following loop execution.
- Includes some basic logic to printout a `No time match found!` message for cases in which the loop exits without matching as per your criteria.

```py
import re

am = ['a.m.', 'am', 'ante meridiem']
timeinp = 'reminder for 3:30 am'
gettime = None

for a in am:
     gettime = re.search(fr'\b\d?\d:\d\d\b(?= {a})', timeinp)
     if gettime:
            gettime = [ int(i) for i in re.split(':', gettime.group()) ]
            print(gettime)
            break
            
if not gettime:
    print('No time match found!')
```